# Bing Ads PHP Example

Tags: php, bing, bing-api

I'm using the Bing Ads php code for downloading Keyword Performance Reports. Here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bing-ads-reporting-request-and-download-a-keyword-performance-report-in-php.aspx

Is there any way i can specify multiple CampaignID's in my Keyword Performance Report? As of now, i'm only able to download reports for a single CampaignID and as you can imagine, this is really inefficient since i have more than 10 Campaigns. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
 $report->Scope->Campaigns = array ();
```

Just have the line below and it will pull all campaigns. It only pulls on campaign level if they are specified.

```
$report->Scope->Campaigns = null;
```